# ArrayList capacity increment equation

Tags: java, arraylist

In the JDK 1.7 into the ArrayList.java the method `ensureCapacity` increments the array capacity using the following expression: `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1)` so it seems that the new capacity will be almost the 50% more than the old.

However in many books is said that the capacity is doubled... so the books aren't updated or I don't understand well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're understanding is correct, newCapacity is 50% more than oldCapacity

In Java 6 newCapacity is calculated as

```
int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
```

This is the beauty of an open source language such as Java, you can see the implementation - if it doesn't fit your requirements, you can implement your own.

Comment: so presumably `new ArrayList(0).add(1);` works in 1.6 but breaks (IndexOutOfBoundsException) in 1.7

Comment: I would expect the array list to be expanded - the parameter is just the initial capacity.   I'd be very surprised if that threw an exception.

Comment: Yes my bad. Just had a look at the source code and in both 1.6 and 1.7 the array size increases by 1 each time if started with `new ArrayList(0)`.

Answer (score 6):

From the [`ArrayList` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The details of the growth policy are
>   not specified beyond the fact that
>   adding an element has constant
>   amortized time cost.

In other words, the books may be accurate for other implementations, but nothing's guaranteed - and the Java 7 source is still compliant with the docs, but shows the books to be overly specific.

Comment: How can be the JDK 7 compliant with the docs if it provides that expression? There the detail of how to calculate the growth policy is setted!

Comment: The growth policy is not specified in the documentation, its got to be specified in the source code, thats what source code is, but as you can see, the implementation has been changed (probably because lshift is a faster operation than multiply & divide.

Comment: @xdevel2000: Which bit of the JDK 7 implementation is incompatible with what I've quoted? Are you saying that adding an element *doesn't* have constant amortized time cost? The documentation gives *a* guarantee, but still leaves room for flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayLists in Java increments the capacity by 50%. However, the vector class in Java, which functions similarly to ArrayLists but offers synchronization, will double capacity. This is likely where the confusion in your books came from.

Answer (score 0):

In **Java 6** newCapacity is calculated as => **int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;**

In **Java 7** newCapacity is calculated as => **int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1)**